# How to use fragment shader from glslsandbox.com

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

i want experiment with ShaderMaterial material from Three.js. But i don't know OpenGl Shading language.When i use fragment shader code in above site,i get a bunch or errors.So i dont know vertex and fragment shader depend with each other or no matter.If is right what i should write in vertex shader.Thank 
My copy-pasted vertex shader for BoxGeometry

```
        uniform float time;
    varying vec2 vUv;
    varying vec2 surfacePosition;
    uniform vec2 resolution;

    void main()
    {
    vec3 posChanged = position;
    posChanged.x = posChanged.x*(abs(sin(time*1.0)));
    posChanged.y = posChanged.y*(abs(cos(time*1.0)));
    posChanged.z = posChanged.z*(abs(sin(time*1.0)));
    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(posChanged,1.0);
    }
```

I want use this  fragment shader [glslsandbox.com](http://glslsandbox.com/e#21082.0)

Comment: Or i need some variables set in THREE.js?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example mostly copied from [this sample](http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_shader.html) but but with the default glslsandbox.com shader inserted

```js
var $ = document.querySelector.bind(document);

var camera = new THREE.Camera();
camera.position.z = 1;

var scene = new THREE.Scene();

var geometry = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(2, 2);

var uniforms = {
  time: { type: "f", value: 1.0 },
  resolution: { type: "v2", value: new THREE.Vector2() },
  mouse: { type: "v2", value: new THREE.Vector2() },
};

var material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
  uniforms: uniforms,
  vertexShader: $('#vs').text,
  fragmentShader: $('#fs').text,
});

var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
scene.add(mesh);

var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
renderer.domElement.addEventListener('mousemove', recordMousePosition);

render(0);

function recordMousePosition(e) {
  // normalize the mouse position across the canvas
  // so in the shader the values go from -1 to +1
  var canvas = renderer.domElement;
  var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();

  uniforms.mouse.value.x = (e.clientX - rect.left) / canvas.clientWidth  *  2 - 1;
  uniforms.mouse.value.y = (e.clientY - rect.top ) / canvas.clientHeight * -2 + 1;      
}

function resize() {
  var canvas = renderer.domElement;
  var dpr    = window.devicePixelRatio;  // make 1 or less if too slow
  var width  = canvas.clientWidth  * dpr;
  var height = canvas.clientHeight * dpr;
  if (width != canvas.width || height != canvas.height) {
    renderer.setSize( width, height, false );
    uniforms.resolution.value.x = renderer.domElement.width;
    uniforms.resolution.value.y = renderer.domElement.height;
  }
}

function render(time) {
  resize();
  uniforms.time.value = time * 0.001;
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}
```

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
canvas {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script id="vs" type="not-js">
void main() {
  gl_Position = vec4( position, 1.0 );
}
</script>
<script id="fs" type="not-js">
precision mediump float;

uniform float time;
uniform vec2 mouse;
uniform vec2 resolution;

void main() {
  vec2 position = (gl_FragCoord.xy / resolution.xy) + mouse / 4.0;

  float color = 0.0;
  color += sin(position.x * cos(time / 15.0) * 80.0) + cos(position.y * cos(time / 15.0) * 10.0);
  color += sin(position.y * sin(time / 10.0) * 40.0) + cos(position.x * sin(time / 25.0) * 40.0);
  color += sin(position.x * sin(time /  5.0) * 10.0) + sin(position.y * sin(time / 35.0) * 80.0);
  color *= sin(time / 10.0) * 0.5;

  gl_FragColor = vec4(vec3(color, color * 0.5, sin(color + time / 3.0) * 0.75), 1.0);
}
</script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r74/three.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, it is working perfect from glslsandbox.com to three.js!

Comment: gman, do you know how to set depth to this example shader to be able to zoom in/out and pan/rotate with mouse in Three.ja?